# Write() with multiprocessing: built-in locking to prevent garbled output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, multiprocessing

My apologies, everyone.  Additional study convinces me that the parallel writing of a single file by multiple processes described below is **much rarer than I originally thought**, and so I don't feel nearly as confident that I have lots of experience with no ill effects.  **More likely I'm just getting lucky** and the data pool is small enough that it just hasn't broken **yet**.

For posterity, this was my original question:

> I'm hoping someone can help me understand what I'm seeing.
>
> I started with a single process that writes multiple files.  Over time it evolved into multiple processes (using ProcessPoolExecutor from concurrent.futures).  During that evolution I unintentionally wound up with **multiple processes writing to the same files in parallel**.
>
> What puzzles me is that **it seems to be working fine**.  At least to date (and it's been months of generating millions of lines of data every day), I **haven't observed a single garbled record**.  Is it possible that there's some kind of **protection built in** somewhere that "atomizes" my write()s somehow, preventing them from interrupting each other?
>
> FWIW, I'm using Python 3.4.

BTW, in response to some comments below, there's lots of computation in addition to the writing, so I need processes, not threads.  And there are upwards of 32 processors, writing 300-400-character text lines.   Thanks again for your input, folks.

Comment: you shouldn't use multiprocessing for writing files instead use multithreading. reason: wiring to files do not involve any computation.

Comment: Providing writing is all the processes are doing. If they're doing any meaningful computational work, threads won't be near as efficient.

Comment: I'm not aware of any implicit synchronization that would occur. How many processes are writing simultaneously? How long are the lines? This could just be a fluke if the conditions make collisions rare.

Comment: It also depends on how you flush to disk. If you write only complete lines at once, a conflict would just mean that some lines are skipped (because one process is overwriting the changes made by another), and no garbling would occur. You could open your file exclusively on writing ('x' mode), so opening the file from another process would fail - and add handling in case of failure (e.g. wait a bit and try again).

Comment: I am actually unable to produce messed-up output using a simple [test program](https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/d9fbc05052dc4407e90200672594b3d9). It does seem to lock the file during a write (on Linux. I don't know if this behavior is at all OS specific). Even multi-line chunks are preserved.

Comment: Your last finding is interesting, @Carcigenicate.  It tempts me to let the code be, but without a guarantee, I hesitate.  Relying on "I haven't been able to break it" is not always our safest bet, as I'm sure you are aware.  :-)

Comment: Ya, without a definitive answer, err on the side of caution.

Comment: I guess if the underlying write syscall can be done atomically (small enough buffer to write etc.), this could happen. But I'd not count on that...

Comment: Either way, if possible, I'd structure this to have each subprocess write to their own file.

Comment: Agreed @AKX.  It's back to working that way (only one process ever writes to any one file) and I can sleep at night.  Thanks!